# Querydsl.JPQLQuery getting the number of records

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, querydsl

Is there any way to just get the count of records from the JPQL query without forming the list?
As when there are more number of records this will impact the performance. This is what I have done so far. Using querydsl-3.7.4

```
Expression[] groupByExpression = // getting the group by Expression
Predicate whereCondition = // getting the where condition predicate

long count = query.from(myEntityName)
                  .where(whereCondition)
                  .groupBy(groupByExpression)
                  .list(constructorExpression).size()
```

Comment: using blazebit can help  https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.5/core/manual/en_US/index.html#querydsl-integration

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade to Querydsl 4 or 5 and use `.fetchCount()` instead of `fetch()` (which is the alternative to `list()` as of Querydsl 4).

Comment: Is there anyother way. I am using 3.7.4 version and don't have the permission to upgrade to latest.

Comment: Querydsl 3 is unmaintained for 5 years now. Probably an alternative for `fetchCount()` exists there, but who still knows after five years ;-)

Comment: And now `fetchCount()` is deprecated.

Comment: Yes, with the limitations of JPA it is not possible to generate a proper count query under all circumstances (i.e. queries with a having clause). I recommend just writing a query that returns the desired count: `query.select(Expressions.count()).from(...).fetchOne()`.